# Do ping-pong at regular interval using Tornado websocket

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am new to Tornado server in python and trying to a ping-pong at regular interval to the clients connected. 
I saw something called `websocket_ping_interval` in tornado documentation but couldn't find any example as to how/when to use it.

I did the below using `ioloop.PeriodicCallback` but doesn't seem to be doing any ping.

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import ioloop
from terminado import TermSocket, SingleTermManager
from tornado import websocket


# BaseWebSocketHandler removed, because we need to track all opened
# sockets in the class. You could change this later.
class MeterInfo(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    """Establish an websocket connection and send meter readings."""
    opened_sockets = []
    previous_meter_reading = 0

    def open(self):
        self.write_message('Connection Established.')
        MeterInfo.opened_sockets.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        """Close the connection."""
        self.write_message('bye')
        MeterInfo.opened_sockets.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def try_send_new_reading(cls):
        """Send new reading to all connected clients"""
        new_reading = "text"

        if new_reading == cls.previous_meter_reading:
            return

        cls.previous_meter_reading = new_reading

        for socket in cls.opened_sockets:
            socket.write_message({'A': new_reading})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    term_manager = SingleTermManager(shell_command=['bash'])
    handlers = [
        (r"/websocket", TermSocket, {'term_manager': term_manager}),
        (r"/()", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'index.html'}),
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '.'}),
    ]
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers)
    app.listen(8010)
    METER_CHECK_INTERVAL = 100  # ms
    ioloop.PeriodicCallback(MeterInfo.try_send_new_reading,METER_CHECK_INTERVAL).start()
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

All I need to do is to keep pinging the clients connected with something.

Comment: I don't see `MeterInfo` handler registered in the  `handlers` list. Your code seems ok otherwise.

Comment: could you advise on how to add this `MeterInfo` handler in the handlers?

Comment: Exactly like it's done with TermSocket: `(r"/meter_info_ws", MeterInfo),`.

Answer (score 5):

`websocket_ping_interval` is an application setting, so you pass it to the `Application` constructor:

```
app = tornado.web.Application(handlers, websocket_ping_interval=10)
```

Comment: Yes I did that simple thing too. But I am not able to see any data in the frames section of chrome dev-tools. Basically not sure if the ping-pong is really happening.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati if you trying to capture the TCP packets between client and Tornado server, you'll find that Tornado is pushing data to client every 10 seconds.

Comment: How can we access and reset the ping timer? I would like to reset it every time we get on_message() to the server